# Block FaceTime/Whatsapp video

Tags: networking, firewall, sip

I want to avoid video calls in my network, mainly from whatsapp and FaceTime.

Ideally, the phone shouldn’t even receive the ring, but it might not be possible as the ring is certainly sent differently than the rest. 2nd choice is simply: No video.

According to doc found online, (i.e.: 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202078) I know which ports are used but not which for which usage. If it’s possible, how can I determine that?

Comment: If the user device, can or use LTE, you already lost the control over that. The only control you have is to block your users to bring their own devices.

Comment: @yagmoth555-GoFundMeMonica  [other comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/993148/block-facetime-whatsapp-video/993152#comment1292113_993152)

Comment: My comment was more, if any user use LTE or his mobile coverage network, he bypass anything you set inside your router.

Comment: It won’t be an issue, as long as it’s not in our network. We want users using our network not being able to use video calls. If they’re using LTE, it’s fine, they will video call freely and outside our network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to determine what ports FaceTime uses would be to start capturing packets on the network, start a FaceTime call, and look at the ports used.

However based off [Apple's listed ports](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202078), and knowing that FaceTime uses STUN (Session Traversal Utilities for NAT) protocol, blocking UDP ports 3478-3497 should suffice.

Keep in mind that STUN is widely used in VoIP applications, and blocking its ports will most likely cause issues for other VoIP traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Since Facetime and What app is encrypted traffic, It would not be possible to block 
video unless the apps use a different URL for text messages and video. Knowing the port numbers does not help because you cannot just block a port without disrupting other services. From my experience, you are fighting a losing battle. Unless you own the devices connecting to your network, you can not easily control what is done on those devices.

Comment: I understand that ports are not “service” specific here. Even if I owned the device, is there a way to block video calls?

Comment: For IOS devices, you can control what apps are allowed to be installed See: https://www.apple.com/business/it/ You could block the facetime app which would solve your problem. For WhatsApp, I am not sure what your options are but you could completely block that app too.

Comment: the issue isn’t the app, I would like our users too be able to use WhatsApp, FaceTime, iMessage for text and audio calls, just not for video

Comment: Unless the developers have created the ability to block video via the apple configuration utility, then there is no way to do this. While you can try and figure out what url and ports facetime uses, chances are you will either break something else or the ports and urls will change.

Comment: I’m convinced (by your answer) that ports aren’t used specifically for video or calls. I’m just answering to others about my needs, but I understood it’s not feasible